# Restatement of a result on the gcd of two integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I read the following statememt:

> Let $(a, b) \in \mathbb Z^2$. An integer is the sum of a multiple of $a$ and a multiple of $b$ if and only if it is a multiple of their gcd  which we denote $a\wedge b$ :
> $$a\mathbb Z + b\mathbb Z = ( a\wedge b )\mathbb Z$$

Can I rewrite this as follows:

> Let $a,b,x$ three integers.
>
> $(a\wedge b)|x$ if and only if  there exists integers $u$ and $v$ such that
> $x=au+bv$

My second question is that if we find the following relation between integers $y=\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2$ then can we say that all  of the four following results are **simultaneously** true:

1)$(\alpha_1\wedge \alpha_2)|y$

2)$(\alpha_1\wedge x_2)|y$

3)$(x_1\wedge \alpha_2)|y$

4)$(x_1\wedge x_2)|y$

thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

First question: Yes.

Say $(a \wedge b) \mid x$. By Bezout's lemma, there are integers $u'$ and $v'$ such that $au' + bv' = a \wedge b$, so we can just scale up to get the $u$ and $v$ that make $x$. The converse comes directly from your second question.

Second question: Also yes!

Since $(\alpha_1 \wedge \alpha_2)$ must divide $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, it must divide any linear combination thereof, namely, $y$. The other three cases use identical logic.

Also, this is unusual notation. I'm curious, which book is this from?

Comment: This notation of gcd is very common in french mathematical litterature.

Comment: Ah, okay. I have enough trouble with math in English, so I don't really know much about notations used elsewhere. Is $\vee$ used for LCM as well?

Comment: yes exactly, that's the notation for lcm !!